# DropdownListFor Validation issue in jQuery when onchange Submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**DropdownListFor**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedDateFilter, 
                      new SelectList(Model.bydatefilter, "id", "dt", Model.selectedDateFilter), 
                      "--Select Date--", 
                      new { onchange = @"this.form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#selectedDateFilter").change(function (e) {       

        if ($("#selectedDateFilter option:selected").index() == 0) {
            alert("Please select the date.");
            return false;            
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Hello Friends,

My issue is that the when select an item in dropdownlist the validation message is displaying as expected but at the same time, the form is submitting.

How to prevent the Form to submit when I select the OPtionText in this Scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Please help

Comment: How you are submitting the `form`? through `ajax`?

Comment: You do not need the 4th parameter in the `SelectList` constructor - its already set based on the value of the property. Why are you not using validation attributes? And why do you have `onchange` in the markup and a `.change()` function?

Comment: No, I'm not using ajax. I'm directly submitting the Form, so that It will hit the respective post action method.

Comment: remove onchange=@"this.form.submit();"  setting on the dropdownlist element. Submit the form when your jquery validation passes

Comment: @Ben Narube Thanks alot Friend, I followed your suggestion and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `onchange=@"this.form.submit();"` from dropdown list. It should look like this below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedDateFilter, 
                      new SelectList(Model.bydatefilter, "id", "dt", Model.selectedDateFilter), 
                      "--Select Date--", 
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It will work fine.

This `onchange=@"this.form.submit();"` forces the form to submit.

EDIT:

Add this to jquery if you want to submit when its validated properly:

```
$("#selectedDateFilter").change(function (e) {       

        if ($("#selectedDateFilter option:selected").index() == 0) {
            alert("Please select the date.");
            return false;            
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).parent('form').submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I need to submit the form on selectedindex change but when we select the  OptionText, I need to validate.

Comment: Thanks alot. The issue is reolved